# Counting string elements of a column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a DataFrame, where I am counting the elements in two columns within and across different rows. Each of the rows in each of the columns has many different elements.

Example of my DataFrame:

```
   col_1                  col_2
0  [AbC, DE, FG]         ['abc', 'de', 'fg']
1  [IJ]                  ['ij']
2  [DE, IJ]              ['de', 'ij']
3  []                    []
4  [AbC, de]             ['abc', 'de']
```

This DataFrame is a very simple representation, and the difference between the two columns in my df is that the second column has been created by converting all the elements in the 1st column to lowercase. That is, by applying the following command:

```
df['col_1'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

As you might notice, the elements in col_2 have '' around each of the elements whereas col_1 elements are without it. I tried making a sample DataFrame to replicate here, but could not get one without the '' as in col_1.

I applied the following command to count the individual elements:

```
Counter(df['col_1'].explode())
```

It works for col_1, but not for col_2.

Expected frequency output that I want to get:

```
abc: 2
de: 3
fg: 1
ij: 3
```

The output can be a list or a dictionary, as long as it can be used for further analysis.
I hope that the Dataframe is reproducible. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How you create this dataframe, I couldn't understand your `col_1` column value `[AbC, DE, FG], [IJ]`. Is `AbC` a value or a variable? What does comma represent?

Comment: Every row is a list with 1 to many string values. Since I did not manually create it, I am not sure how to reproduce it. It is a list of words (hashtags) that were taken from a text by using: df['text'].str.findall(r'#(\w+)')

Comment: I forgot to mention that the df['col_1'].astype(str).str.lower() did not work without the astype() even though the type was object before which is the same as string, I think. But, now the counter command does not work probably due to the '' around the elements/values.

Answer (score 2):

If col_2 is needed then you can use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
data = {
    'col_1': [
        ['AbC','DE','FG'], 
        ['IJ'],
        ['DE','IJ'],
        [],
        ['AbC', 'de']
        ],

    'col_2': [
        ['abc','de','fg'], 
        ['ij'],
        ['de','ij'],
        [],
        ['abc', 'de']
        ]
}

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Flatten all sub-lists into a master list
master_list = [element for sublist in data_frame["col_2"].tolist() for element in sublist]

# Use counter to group and count
print(Counter(master_list))
```

**Output**:

```
Counter({'de': 3, 'abc': 2, 'ij': 2, 'fg': 1})
```

If col_2 isn't needed then you can perform the .lower() as you iterate through items when creating the flattened list.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
data = {
    'col_1': [
        ['AbC','DE','FG'], 
        ['IJ'],
        ['DE','IJ'],
        [],
        ['AbC', 'de']
        ]
}

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Flatten all sub-lists into a master list
master_list = [element.lower() for sublist in data_frame["col_1"].tolist() for element in sublist]

# Use counter to group and count
print(Counter(master_list))
```

**Output**:

```
Counter({'de': 3, 'abc': 2, 'ij': 2, 'fg': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When I apply your code to my DataFrame, it counts each letter separately. As in 'd':3 and 'e':3 and so on. It even calculates the times that '' appears in the column. I also had to add .astype(str) to the [element.lower() for sublist in data_frame["col_1"].astype().tolist() for element in sublist]. Without it, it just said that float is not hashable. I am guessing that there is something different in my dataset, but I can't seem to find out.

Comment: when I check for the type it says object. but then when I try to run the code without .astype(str), it says it is a float.

Comment: It looks like you're building col_1 with objects rather than strings.  Add quotes around each grouping of characters you want to count.

Comment: How can I add the quotes?

Comment: But the problem is with the col_2 where the quotes are present and it is string. For col_1, using the code: Counter(df['col_1'].explode()), counts the words and not the letters. While if I apply the same command for counting to col_2, it counts each and every letter separately.